# Hangman updating OO value array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am writing a hangman game in PHP and JS and I am having problems. I have two arrays,
an answer array which has the correct letters,
and a user answer array which contains the users correct guesses.

The user answer guesses array starts out with underscores as no guesses have been correct _  _  _

I would like to update this array and put the correct letter into the correct field when the user guesses correctly _ A _;

When I var_dump inside the updateAnswer() function the user answer array has changed and added the correct letter, however when I pull from returnUserAnswer the array is has not.

PS. the library is only being called once so __construct is not a problem.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Word {

private $answer;
public $usrAnswer;

function __construct(){
$this->answer = array('C','A','T');
$this->usrAnswer = array('_','_','_');
}
function returnUserAnswer(){
return $this->usrAnswer;
}

function updateAnswer($letter,$try){
    $change = array($try => $letter);
    $this->usrAnswer = array_replace($this->usrAnswer,$change);

}

function guess($letter){

    $try = array_search($letter,$this->answer);

    if($try === FALSE){ 
    return false;
    }else{ 
    $this->updateAnswer($letter,$try);return $try;      
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the JavaScript tag, I'm assuming you're writing a hangman implementation that uses AJAX requests. If this assumption is correct then this statement of yours is as false as can be:

> PS. the library is only being called once so `__construct` is not a problem.

PHP is stateless. That means that, for every request that the server receives, your class is instantiated, and when the response is sent, all of the changes to all instances are lost. As a result, here's what an ajax-driven flow looks like:

```
[request 1] => new Word --> constructor initialize $usrAnswer to ['_','_','_']
                                        initialize $answer to ['C', 'A', 'T']
            => destroy instances and resources
            => send response

[request 2] => guess a letter (send via AJAX)
            => new Word --> constructor is called, same as request 1
            => update $usrAnswer
            => destroy instance
            => send response

[request 3] => see [request 2]
[request N] => see [request 2]
```

What you need to do, then, is have JavaScript send the full state of the guessed answer on every request, not just a single letter. Something like the following object will do:

```
var requestData = {
    state: {
        validGuesses: ['A'],
        invalidGuesses: ['X', 'Q'] //<-- number of attempts, check if current guess is not a duplicate
    },
    guess: 'C'
};
```

Then, server-side (in PHP), change your constructor to take arguments (an array in this case will do). As an aside, the code below applies the [coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org), which I really recommend you to follow, too:

```
public function __construct(array $userState = array())
{
    $this->answer = ['C', 'A', 'T'];
    $this->usrAnswer = ['_','_','_'];
    foreach ($userState as $value) {
        $key = array_search($value, $this->answer);
        if ($key === false) {
            //handle invalid state, I'd suggest:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('%s is not a valid answer', $value)
            );
        }
        $this->usrAnswer[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Now, when you call `guess`, the value of `$usrAnswer` will be correct.

*Update:*
To clarify my last comment (about adding an `$answer` argument to the constructor), here's what I'd do:

```
public function __construct($answer = 'CAT', array $state = [])
{
    $this->answer = str_split(strtoupper($answer));//ensure upper-case, create array
    //create array containing the correct amount of _ chars
    $this->usrAnswer = array_fill(0, strlen($answer), '_');
    foreach ($state as $value) {
        $key = array_search($value, $this->answer);
        if ($key === false) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('%s is not a valid answer', $value)
            );
        }
        $this->usrAnswer[$key] = $value;
    }
    //replace _ with dash, if the answer contains dashes (eg ice-cream)
    $pos = -1;
    while (($pos = strpos($answer, '-', $pos +1)) !== false) {
        $this->usrAnswer[$pos] = '-';
    }
}
```

As far as using the class is concerned, nothing really changes:

```
$cat = new Word();
```

Except for when an ajax request needs processing:

```
$cat = new Word('cat', $state);//where $state is the request data
```

Another example:

```
$iceCream = new Word('ice-cream', ['C', 'A']);
//sets usrAnswer to _C_-C__A_
$iceCream->guess('I');
//usrAnswer is now IC_-C__A_
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, I was unaware of this, thank you for the thorough answer I shall study it!

Comment: @JoeSmith: You're welcome. PS: I'd also suggest you allow for a second argument in your constructor to pass the `$answer` value to the instance: `public function __construct($answer, array $userState = []);`, then you can use the length of `$answer` to create the `$usrAnswer` array, which makes your class a lot more flexible

Comment: @JoeSmith: Updated my answer, but to get some more feedback on how you can improve on your class, it'd be best to submit your code [on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). The site has just graduated from the beta stage, and is well worth a look